# xQuery swap attribute values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xquery, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to write a query that gets xml form a database and flips two attribute values if a certain character is found. So for example:

```
<people>
   <person name="Alice" age="20" team="developer" dep="red" version="old" />
   <person name="Sam" age="23" team="marketing" dep="blue" version="old" />
   <person name="Bob" age="21" team="sales" dep="green" version="new" />
</people>
```

If `version="old"`, then I want to flip the team and colour attribute. So Alice will have:

```
<person name="Alice" age="20" team="red" dep="developer" version="new" />
```

I have the database returning rows with only "old", however I don't know how to replace the attributes.

```
UPDATE mDB
        SET people.modify('
            for $p in (/people/person)
                let $team := $p/@team
                let $dep := $p/@dep

                replace value of node
                    $p/@dep
                with 
                    $team
                replace value of node
                    $p/@team
                with 
                    $dep
        ')
        FROM mDB
        WHERE   people.exist('
                    for $p in (/people/person)
                        where contains( data( $p/@version ), "old" )
                    return data( $person/@version)') != 0
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using SQL 2014, service pack 1, does that help?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes i am! sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell if your SQL/XQuery mix is using XQuery's native updating function or if this comes from your sql vendor, but a quick look at the docs should tell you.

You currently tell XQuery to update the value of a node, where what your want is to update the value of an attribute, ie if you replace `$p/@dep` with `$p/@team` the result will just be that `@dep` and `@team` switch their order in the output. `<person team='x' dep='1'/>` will become `<person dep='1' team='x'/>` You need to keep the node as is, but only replace the value of the attributes. Something like this:

```
for $p in people/person[@version = "old"]
return
    element person { 
        attribute name {data($p/@name)}, 
        attribute age {data($p/@age)}, 
        attribute team {data($p/@dep)}, (: <- note the switch :)
        attribute dep {data($p/@team)}, (: <- s.a. :)
        attribute version {data($p/@version)}
    }
```

will produce the desired output:

```
<person name="Alice" age="20" team="red" dep="developer" version="old"/>
<person name="Sam" age="23" team="blue" dep="marketing" version="old"/>
```

Comment: This seems to be doing what I want!

Is there a way to get it to return the root element 'people' while its looping? Or do I have to do another query for that? Because what if I add attributes to the root element, how  would I be ape to update the required person elements without losing the root attribute data?

Comment: just replace `element person` with `element $p/..` my answer constructed a new person element, based on your example, if you want to reuse the old people element, you can get there using xpath parent steps.